# How can I get Browsable(false) to actually hide the property in the IDE

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, components

Good Afternoon,

I've created a user-defined component that has a boolean property.  I would like Visual studio do NOT SHOW it on the property Window.  I've googled extensively and the consensus seems to be to try to use the Browsable/BrowsableAttribute property descriptors.

Visual Studio appears to be ignoring this attribute altogether.  I've tried building all my projects, resetting the toolbox to no avail.  Please help.

Thanks and regards,
-Alan.

```
[Browsable(false)]  // I have also tried [BrowsableAttribute(false)]
public bool IsBusy
{
    get
    {
        return _isBusy;
    }
    set
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("");
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't even throw the exception when the IDE let's me edit the property from false to true!

Comment: @Alan - why don't you make it a readonly property?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I've tried making it a readonly property [ReadOnly(true)] as well as [ReadOnlyAttribute(true)].  Also did not work :(

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 (sorry for omitting that)

Comment: @Alan - Not like that. Leave out the `set` block. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04(v=VS.100).aspx#Y1800. You can use a public method to set the property if you need to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really is [Browsable].  Omitting the setter would be another way, that makes sense in this scenario.

I'm guessing the real problem you have is an old copy of this control stored in the toolbox assembly folder.  Such a copy is made if you add the control to the toolbox yourself with Choose Items, Browse tab.  You might be updating your local copy but not the toolbox version.

I need to wave my hands at this a bit, I know it can happen but never discovered how it happens.  This never went wrong for me personally, but I always make sure to let the toolbox auto-populate itself instead of adding the control explicitly.  If you did add it like this then start by removing it.  Right-click the item in the toolbox and select Delete.  The copy is stored in c:\users\yourname\appdata\local\microsoft\visualstudio\x.x\projectassemblies

Comment: Worked -- I just removed the whole directory (too anoyed to find the exact offending file).  Also, I strongly-named my control library so i could double-check the version on the toolbox (the tooltip shows the version).

Comment: in short -- 1) strongly-name control/component library & rebuild, 2) close visual studio, 3) nuke that directory, 4) open Visal Studio, 5) reset toolbox.